# MySQL запрос ограниченный запросом оператора IN

Tags: mysql, select

Задача: выполнить запрос, который зависит от выполнения запроса оператора in. Т. е. запрос будет делаться из админки некого супер-пользователя, который имеет список других пользователей-рефералов, ранее им зарегистрированных. Нужно, чтобы при удалении проверялось, есть ли реферал в списке супер-пользователя.

Примерный код:

```
DELETE
FROM (`users`)
WHERE `user_id` IN (SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `referrals` = `super_user_id`)
AND `status` = '1'
```

Таблица users

```
| user_id | referrer_id | name  | status |
-----------------------------------------
| 1000    | 0           | user1 | 1      |
-----------------------------------------
| 1001    | 0           | user2 | 1      |
-----------------------------------------
| 1002    | 0           | user3 | 0      |
-----------------------------------------
| 1010    | 1000        | user4 | 1      |
-----------------------------------------
| 1020    | 1000        | user5 | 1      |
-----------------------------------------
```

В данном случае супер-пользователь `(referrer_id = 0)` с `user_id = 1000` имеет два реферала `user_id (1010 , 1020)`. При удалении какого либо из них нужно проверить являются ли они рефералами именно пользователя с user_id = 1000. Т.к. можно при удалении указать значение user_id = 1001 и удалить другого супер-пользователя.

Comment: Вы бы в запросе писали какая колонка из какой таблицы а то ничего не ясно.

Comment: А вообще вам нужен `delete A.* from users A JOIN users B on ....` условия склейки сами придумаете

Comment: Что имеется ввиду *проверялось, есть ли реферал*? В таком случае не удалять?

Comment: Дополнил описание.